# wordpress woocommerce php variable usage %1$s

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wordpress with woocommerce and I am trying to manipulate a copy of myaccount.php  The default code uses some variables of some sort that I am not familiar with nor have I been able to find documentation on.  The variables in question are %1$s, %2$s and %s

```
<p class="myaccount_user">
<?php
printf(
    __( 'Hello <strong>%1$s</strong> (not %1$s? <a href="%2$s">Sign out</a>).', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ',
    $current_user->display_name,
    wp_logout_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) )
);
?>

<?php
printf( __( 'From this page you can view your recent orders, manage your shipping and billing addresses and <a href="%s">edit your password and account details</a>.', 'woocommerce' ),
    wc_customer_edit_account_url()
);
?>
</p>
```

How can I identify the variables, what they represent and how to use them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%1$s` and `%2$s` are standard "conversion specifications" (ie. *placeholders*) used with the `printf()` family of PHP functions (nothing to do with WordPress or WooCommerce). They are *replaced* with the argument values that are passed to the `printf()` function.

So, in the first example, `%1$s` is replaced with the value of `$current_user->display_name` (1st argument) and `%2$s` is replaced with the value returned from `wp_logout_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) )` (2nd argument).

The placeholder specifies *how* the value is displayed.

- `%` indicates the start of the placeholder.
- The number `1` that follows is a reference to which argument, either 1 or 2 in this example.
- `s` indicates a string.

Further reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php